# Adal.js and Azure Signing Key Rollover

Tags: adal, rollover

I know Adal.js doesn't validate the token, but relies on the webapi for this, but : 
As I can't find any official documentation on this, I'm posting it here just to be sure.

Is this library in any way affected by the Azure Signing Key Rollover : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same and found the answer in the part describing [Web applications / APIs accessing resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/#webclient) in the article you linked.

> #### Web applications / APIs accessing resources
>
> Applications that are only accessing resources (i.e Microsoft Graph, KeyVault, Outlook API and other Microsoft APIs) generally only obtain a token and pass it along to the resource owner. Given that they are not protecting any resources, they do not inspect the token and therefore do not need to ensure it is properly signed.
>
> Web applications and web APIs that are using the app-only flow (client credentials / client certificate), fall into this category and are thus not impacted by the rollover.

You don't need to take action, but if you want to make sure it works:

> You can validate whether your application supports automatic key rollover by downloading the scripts and following the instructions in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-powershell-tokenkey).

**Edit**: Found this in the [comment section of the the same article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-signing-key-rollover/#comment-2821718374):

> The ADAL libraries are only for applications that are acting as clients, helping you retrieve a token. If all you are doing with that token is passing it along to a Microsoft API (e.g. Microsoft Graph, Outlook API, etc) then you are fine. If you are using this token to grant user access to your application or your API, then you need to look at whatever code is validating the token and it's signature to ensure it's pulling the keys from the metadata.